# Voltage follower with a RF signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, rf, impedance, datasheet

I have a RF signal up to 50 MHz coming from a VCO which I want to use on a different impedance circuit. Without any adaptation the signal go down quickly when i raise the frequency because my load is capacitive (it's a sort a capacitance meter).

So I try to find the good operational amplifier to make a voltage follower in order to adapt my VCO output with my circuit. But I fail to obtain good results, I'm still a student so my knowledges are limited.

My adaptation circuit :
[image: My adaptation circuit]

I've read that a small resistance as 50 Ohm can help with capacitive loads. But I'm searching for the right amplifier, I've found this one :http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1808735.pdf and my VCO is a TEXAS INSTRUMENTS  SN74S124N

What parameters are important in this case ?

Comment: How much load capacitance and what voltage signal?

Comment: What amp is that?

Comment: It may help to search for video amps. There should definitely be some available that can drive a 50 Ohm load at 50 MHz.

Comment: Why dont you use a cheap easy JFET like MPF102?

Comment: Why don't you just do wide impedance matching for that? What difference will using an op amp make? Tell the output impedance of the VCO and and input impedance of the other circuit you wanna use. Other than analog applications there is no use of buffers. Especially in RF aplications.

Comment: @Alperözel, buffering 50 MHz with an op-amp is easy. You just have to pick the right op-amp.

Comment: @Andyaka the voltage signal is in the same order of the supply voltage : 5V. I've measured that it's typicaly a -1.5V to + 4V signal.

Comment: Well you can't put -1.5 volts into your op-amp circuit and even if you level shifted it from 0 to 5.5 volts you'd need a bigger supply rail.

Comment: @LeonHeller I try with AD8031 but I'm not sure at all that it's the good, here is the reason of my question

Comment: @mkeith sure, I've searched in this area, but I still need to know chat all parameters mean to chose the good one

Comment: @Alperözel cause it's a pure analog application, I'm trying to measure a capacitive interaction, so the analog impedance is variable

Comment: @Andyaka I'm not sure that my measures were right because in the VCO datasheet http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1967831.pdf there is a 0.5 V min output voltage line. So the theoretical amplitude is around 3 or 3.5 V

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear exactly what you need, but a few things seem clear. The first is that your 74S124 produces a digital output, so you can use a digital buffer rather than an op amp. Furthermore, your -1.5 volt output occurs as a result of bad physical layout interacting with the sharp fall time of the VCO, and does not represent a guaranteed effect.

Buffering the VCO with a high-speed buffer such as the 74FCT244 would seem to be your best bet. These are available from sources such as Digikey for a buck apiece. The circuit would look like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs5zdf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
This will not provide perfect amplitude stability, but should probably be adequate for your needs. The output current capacity of the FCT244 is great enough that you should not have problems.